# Explain situation when you might use touch-action: manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have seen

```
touch-action: manipulation;
```

In the CSS of various websites applied to buttons and links.  I am curious what the purpose of this is?

I read the values on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action)

> The touch-action CSS property specifies whether, and in what ways, a
>   given region can be manipulated by the user (for instance, by panning
>   or zooming).
>
> **auto:**
>   The user agent may determine any permitted touch behaviors, such
>   as panning and zooming manipulations of the viewport, for touches that
>   begin on the element.
>
> **none:** Use this value to disable all of the
>   default behaviors and allow your content to handle all touch input
>   (touches that begin on the element must not trigger default touch
>   behaviors).
>
> **pan-x:** 
>   The user agent may consider touches that begin on
>   the element only for the purposes of horizontally scrolling the
>   element's nearest ancestor with horizontally scrollable content.
>
> **pan-y:**
>   The user agent may consider touches that begin on the element only for
>   the purposes of vertically scrolling the element's nearest ancestor
>   with vertically scrollable content.
>
> **manipulation:** The user agent may
>   consider touches that begin on the element only for the purposes of
>   scrolling and continuous zooming. Any additional behaviors supported
>   by auto are out of scope for this specification.

But I don't understand what the thinking is behind applying this to most  links/buttons.  Does this prevent a common issue that normally comes with using the default value of auto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to sitepoint [post](https://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-prevent-300ms-click-delay-mobile-devices/), `touch-action: manipulation` helps preventing [`PointerEvents`](https://w3c.github.io/pointerevents/) fire by removing each event detection delay. For example, the double-tap event could fire when screen is double-tapped until 300ms case `touch-action: manipulation` was not declared.

Short quote:

> Most touch-based mobile browsers wait 300ms between your tap on the screen and the browser firing the appropriate handler for that event. It was implemented because you could be double-tapping to zoom the page to full width. Therefore, the browser waits for a third of a second — if you don’t tap again, the “click” is activated.
>
> ...
>
> Microsoft has solved many touch-based issues in the PointerEvents
> specification. For example, the pointerup event won’t be fired if the
> user is scrolling the page.
>
> There is also a non-standard CSS touch-action property which allows
> you to remove the delay on specific elements or the whole document
> without disabling pinch-zooming:
>
> a, button, .myelements { ... }

I'm not sure about situations, it depends if you're not satisfied with the screen taps, so comparisons would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I assigned `touch-action: manipulation` to a button, to avoid page zoom on mobile phone on double tapping.